# How to start a sonar-scanner docker image from BitBucket Pipeline?

Tags: docker, sonarqube, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, sonarscanner

I have to run from bitbucket the sonar-scanner that is already configured. Thing is that I am new to all of these: BitBucket, sonar-scanner, docker and I need to integrate them in a way that I can only run the sonar-scanner from BitBucket from this point and then use more advanced analysis from sonar-scanner.

I tried to use a docker image using sonar-scanner, but didn't manage to build it. So I got it from GitHub directly, but didn't manage to use it from bitbucket.

I took a look on this thread but it is using GitLab, even though it is similar to what I need:
[Launching Sonar Scanner from a gitlab docker runner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56251725/launching-sonar-scanner-from-a-gitlab-docker-runner)

**bitbucket-pipelines.yml**

```
# This is a sample build configuration for Docker.
# Check our guides at https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/O1toN for more examples.
# Only use spaces to indent your .yml configuration.
# -----
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.
image: atlassian/default-image:2

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        services:
          - docker
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          # Set $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME and $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD as environment variables in repository settings
          - export IMAGE_NAME=emeraldsquad/sonar-scanner:$BITBUCKET_COMMIT

          # build the Docker image (this will use the Dockerfile in the root of the repo)
          #RETURNS ERROR - docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME .
          # authenticate with the Docker Hub registry
          - docker login --username $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME --password $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD
          # push the new Docker image to the Docker registry
          - docker push $IMAGE_NAME
```